# "doas" not working in alpine 3.18 container

Tags: docker, alpine

I can't get the doas command to work in an alpine 3.18 based container:

```
~$ cat /etc/doas.conf
permit nopass :users as root cmd /test.sh

~$ id
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groups=100(users),1000(me)

~$ doas -C /etc/doas.conf /test.sh
permit nopass

~$ doas /test.sh
doas: Operation not permitted
```

-C says I'm fine but then the actual command won't work. Am I missing something or hitting a bug here? Trimmed down example of course, I tried different commands and specifying my user instead of the group as well as adding -u root and probably everything else I could come up with...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a bug because it works in alpine 3.19.

I'm going to upgrade my base image.